# Как выполнять действие в определенный промежуток времени?

Tags: java, android-studio

Допустим есть команда, как сделать, чтобы она показывалась в определенный промежуток времени, например раз в минуту?

```
Ad.show(this, Ad.INTERSTITIAL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что речь именно про Android. Если сходу, то пара решений:

1. Handler - выполняем `Runnable` таск в GUI потоке периодически.
2. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor - выполняем таск в фоновом потоке.
3. [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).
4. AlarmManager - выполняем в фоне, но с помощью сервисов.
5. TimerTask - ненадежная штука, не рекомендуется к использованию.

Судя по вопросу, вы хотите отображать рекламу периодически или вроде того, значит надо это делать в GUI потоке. Тогда Handler  подойдёт.

```
private static const int DEF_INTERVAL = 500;
private int mInterval = DEF_INTERVAL; 
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    startTask();
}

Runnable mAdShower = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
          try {
               Ad.show(this, Ad.INTERSTITIAL);
          } finally {
               mHandler.postDelayed(mAdShower , mInterval);
          }
    }
};

void startTask() {
    mAdShower.run(); 
}

void stopTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mAdShower);
}
```

Comment: private static const int DEF_INTERVAL = 500 тут значение измеряется в миллисекундах?

Comment: @A.Schtolc да, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)